# How to see "Actual execution plan" of our query in python?

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-execution-plan

I have a sql query in python which is pretty slow, it contain some inner join,

And some one suggest that in this case we can:  turn on the "Show Actual Execution Plan" option and then take a close look at what is causing the slowdown.

Here some one has similar prolem as me : [Slow SQL Query due to inner and left join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104/slow-sql-query-due-to-inner-and-left-join)

Does anyone know how can I see the "Actual Execution Plan" and "estimated Execution Plan" in sqlite inside a python script?

I found some defenitions here :
http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/
But still don't know how to do it in python, Any recommendation?

cheers

Atieh

Answer (score 4):

You issue the [EXPLAIN](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) query the same as you would any other query.

Comment: hint:  add EXPLAIN ANALYZE for more info, in dbs that support it (PG, not sqlite)